How does a country without exit immigration check know you have overstayed?
Do countries without exit immigration check (like US or any other one) know you have overstayed when you're leaving the country?
And if not, does that mean that this overstayed person can easily come back to the same country later on a new valid visa or passport without being detected by the enter immigration and let in with no problem?
My friend, US citizen, just came back from the trip around eu (US-France-Germany-Ireland-London) and at no point, as he said, he saw exit immigration in any of those countries, including European ones.

Just because you don't interact with an "exit check" does not mean the country has no way of knowing you have left.

How did your friend travel from Germany to Ireland?  In my experience, German airports are carefully designed to require anyone boarding a flight to Ireland (or anywhere else outside the Schengen area) to go through passport control.  The US and UK don't do this (I don't know about Ireland), but they do record exits from airline passenger manifests.  If they fail to record the exit, the traveler may have to show that they didn't overstay through other means.

Ask your friend to check their passport again, where an exit stamp for the Schengen Area should exist (France/Germany). A missing exit stamp could lead to problems when re-entering. For the UK/US, the transport firm (Airline etc.) will inform the immigration authorities of the exit.

It’s not just airlines either. Ferries and cross border rail operators such as Eurotunnel also collect and transmit API data to Immigration authorities.

@phoog He traveled by air. No check of passport on exit. That's what he said. I don't think he is lying. I just spoke to him again. He doesn't have any exit stamps in his passport either. Only enter stamp. Possibly they do it through the airlines these days...

@Mark Johnson - Nope, no exit stamp. Only entrance stamp.

@Traveller - Yea probably you're right.

That then was a mistake. If there is a corresponding Irish/UK entry stamp (showing when that person left the Schengen Area), it will have no side effect.

"He traveled by air. No check of passport on exit": which airport did he fly from?

@phoog He flew from Dusseldorf - DUS Airport.

@TanyaKryvoruchenko, the first comment in this series, 'just because<>' is not rude or unfriendly, stop flagging it.

@Willeke, this comment is rude and sarcastic. The comment doesn’t help me get an answer to the question and is unhelpful. It only prompts more comments and clarifications. I don’t understand why person can’t just answer the question if they have something to say, it’s rude to make such comment.

@Kate Gregory, your comment doesn’t help me get an answer to the question. All it does is making me feel stupid for asking. If you have a good answer, I would appreciate you do answer, otherwise please do not bother commenting. For example, jcaron below took time to explain so that I understand, so as others that did take time to answer. Thank you.

Nope @TanyaKryvoruchenko that's not how it works. If I had an answer I would answer. A comment is by definition not an answer. The intent wasn't to make you feel stupid but to provide information that may be helpful.

@TanyaKryvoruchenko, that comment is not rude, it does not stop people from answering, it is what you can expect on this site.

Just a note: the question is a bit generic (which are not ideal on this site): so do you care more about specific case (EU) or very general. Also note: we do not know all information countries exchange (we know they change much more than officially published, but hopefully just for security and not for simple immigration violations). Also note: for future reader: any precise answer will rot quickly: there are many changes around the world (also in Schengen area).

@TanyaKryvoruchenko perhaps there is a language issue here, but the first comment is simply pointing out that passport checks are not the only way that a traveler's exit from a country can be monitored. So the fact that your friend saw no checks doesn't mean that their exit went unrecorded. I honestly don't know what you see that makes you feel it is sarcastic or rude, but I really don't think it was intended to be.

@GiacomoCatenazzi Understood - thank you. I think I've gotten an answer to my question (below). A few very helpful people explained how it works which is totally sufficient for me and appreciated.


Do countries without exit immigration check (like US or any other one) know you have overstayed when you're leaving the country?

Sometimes, but not always. For example, if you leave the US by air, the airline will provide your passport information to the US government, but not everyone leaves the US by air. If you leave by land to Canada, the Canadian government will share information about people entering with the US. But, as of 2023, the Mexican government does not share information about people entering with the US. (See this Congressional Research Service report, page 11 (14th page of the PDF).) Therefore, if the US government does not have a record of someone leaving, it may not be able to distinguish between someone who is still in the US, and someone who has left by land to Mexico.

And if not, does that mean that this overstayed person can easily come
back to the same country later on a new valid visa or passport without
being detected by the enter immigration and let in with no problem?

No. If, upon the next visa application or entry, the officer sees that the person had an entry without a corresponding exit the last time, the officer will probably place the burden upon the person to prove that they left on time (e.g. with an entry stamp to another country, or other evidence that places the person in another country on a certain date).

"the Mexican government does not share information about people entering" - Most of the time the Mexican government doesn't even look at your passports, so it doesn't even have the information itself

@Midavalo if you walk over the border they do check passports/FMM AFAIK. But if you drive then yeah, no checks at all.

I made a U-turn 16 years ago after leaving the U.S. via the San Ysidro border crossing  because my 90 day visa free tourist period was running out. There was no check whatsoever (also not by the Mexicans who don't expect or are not afraid of Norte Americano immigrants, apparently). I needed the exit stamp though exactly to prove my compliance; we turned around, lined up for a few hours on the Mexican side and then had to explain to the U.S. agent that we needed an exit stamp, which took a minute. "We are really punishing the wrong people here", he sighed and let us u-turn again to Mexico.

While there is no check, there is information. Nowadays this is all electronic, but there were other means before that.
For instance, in the US, visitors used to have a part of their I-94 stapled into their passport when they entered the country. On exit, the check-in agent would take it from the passport, and all collected I-94s would be send to the relevant agency. Of course it was extremely inefficient (I have no idea what actual processing was done with those forms, honestly).
Nowadays this is mostly all electronic. Airlines provide manifests (lists of passengers) with more or less information to the relevant authorities, which try to match them to the relevant record (which is straightforward in most cases even with very minimal info, but can be more difficult in special cases like people having multiple passports, possibly with different names, or extremely common names...).
Visitors to the US can see the result by checking their own I-94 online after leaving the US: the exit will (should?) have been recorded even though they never met a CBP agent on their way out.
For a long time there were a number of "holes" in the system, for instance:

In the UK only airlines provided the info (and I think not even all of them). Train (Eurostar), ferry and bus companies didn't. This has been addressed since.

There was a hole for people exiting the UK via Ireland. Since the UK and Ireland are part of the CTA (Common Travel Area), exits to Ireland were not recorded, and either Ireland did not record exists or did not report them to the UK, don't remember which. I think this has been addressed as well.


Also, note that some of the flights in your friend's itinerary (FR-DE and IE-UK) are internal flights/trips (Schengen for the former, CTA for the latter), and don't necessarily have border control at either end anyway.
However there IS exit passport control out of Schengen, so your friend did nearly certainly meet a border agent when they flew from Germany to Ireland. They should have a matching stamp in their passport. If they don't, they should keep evidence that they actually left the Schengen area on that date (boarding passes, hotel receipts in other countries), because those stamps are currently the only record of Schengen entries and exits.
US-France-Germany-Ireland-London-US:

US exit: no check
FR entry: check
FR-DE: internal, no checks other than ID
DE exit: check
IE entry: check
IE-UK: internal, no checks other than ID
UK exit: no check


thank you, very helpful.

In most cases, like in the US or the UK, the airline will report your travel to the authorities themselves (through Advance Passenger Information or API)
I don't know how they could have seen no control in either Germany or Ireland, as, to exit the Schengen Area you must pass border control, and to enter Ireland you must pass entry control

However, those border controls can be achieved using Automatic Passport Control, which some nationalities are eligible to use.
Because this is why I assume happened.
For Germany, EU/EEA/CH citizens + Residents of Germany + pre-registered US/HKSAR/TW/ROK citizens are eligible. But, until the Entry Exit System (EES) is implemented, a stamp is still to be applied.
For Ireland, EU/EEA/CH + US/CA/AUS/NZ/JP citizens (unless transiting to the UK) are eligible.
